# Is there a good remote alternative to asking someone to coffee to pick their brain / break the ice?

Tags: interviewing, networking, telecommute

As many of you may know a tried and true standby for networking is to offer to buy a coffee or lunch so that you can pick their brain (presumably they're worth meeting), break the ice, and get to know them a little better before you blithely proposition them for career help or advice while offering nothing in return (a little appreciation for peoples' time can go a long way in my opinion).

I was curious is anyone had ideas or strategies for remote alternatives.  I'd like to get some recruiters for companies I'm interested on the horn, for instance, and see what they are looking for as well as warm up the lead a little bit.  Just wondering if there's anything I can do while cold e-mailing to make it a bit more friendly.  Thanks!

Comment: This depends **a lot** on local culture, age and gender, and possibly many other factors. I usually challenge my peers to a game (anything from Tic-Tac-Toe to Counter Strike) in order to break the ice. I see that in a lot of places this could get one into trouble, but it's the way the nerds from my generation socialize around here. I could bet it wouldn't work for most people here, but this is just to show how different the ways to break the ice can be.

Comment: Just to confirm, are you looking _specifically_ for _remote networking_ opportunities?  I.e. you want to network with someone who lives across the country?

Comment: @renan That's an interesting idea, but specifically in my case I am looking to make introductions to hiring managers / recruiters.  Asking them to game is likely to be perceived as unprofessional.

Comment: @user809695 Yes, I'd like to network with someone who lives across the country, specifically to warm up job prospects in places like Silicon Valley (I'm located in the Midwest at the moment, and the tech opportunities here are limited).

Comment: Hey user, welcome to [workplace.se]! As explained in our [help/dont-ask], subjective questions that invite people sharing their preference generally aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. If you can find a way to match your question to our guidelines, please [edit] the question and you should get better answers.

Comment: I don't see how you can challenge your peers to a game of Tic-Tac-Toe, unless you're about six years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you're in the Mid West, and considering a move to Silicon Valley, so we're not talking half a world away. If I was in your position, I would book a week off work and fly out west. Email your contacts and say "I'm going to be in town from [date] to [date], and I would love to talk to you about [whatever]."

I'm sure there are ways you can kinda/sorta do this over Skype, or the phone, or email, but in my opinion, face-to-face trumps all.

Comment: Agreed.  I may well have to book a trip to San Francisco . . .

Comment: Alternatively, go to a conference and socialize there.

Answer (score 0):

Pick a good discussion topic, and email the person to ask if you could talk to them on the phone about it.[1]  For example, you could talk about some new technology in your field [2], new regulations, etc.  See an industry trade magazine to get some ideas.  If the conversation is going well, then you can expand it to related topics; and maybe call or email later on to ask for career advice directly.

---

---

[1] Be sure to use the right key-terms ("networking", "just looking for information") to signal your intent.  Getting introduced through a mutual contact would help, too.  You may even try going through several levels of contacts and keep asking, "Do you know anyone else I could talk to?"

[2]Obviously pick something that they are interested in, and you are at least a little interested in. Don't ask about "cloud data storage" if you have no interest in that technology whatsoever.